# What's the process of the micro USB device connect to an android phone?

Tags: android, connection, usb, host

**What's the process of the micro USB device connect to an android phone?**

[Fig1.connection draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps25H.jpg)

Fig1 is my application draft, and more details are as follows:

My cellphone support OTG function and is enabled
As the picture says, my device has connected the ID pin to the ground in order to get the power of 5V.
I connect the D- pin to 5V so that it tells the phone this is a low-speed device.
I have an APP installed on my phone to supervise if there is a device plugged in.

**My aim is when I plug my device into my phone I can get an information on the app.** Do not mind the USB communication between each other.

Questions:

1. Can anybody tell me how is the process when the device connected to
   the cell phone?
2. Is my device schematic right?
3. How can the app get the notification as soon as the device plugin?

In my point of view, as soon as the device plugged in, firstly the ID pin of the micro USB receptacle get a falling edge and thus tell the phone there is a device plugin and the device is working as a HOST.

I wonder if this ID pin signal can trig a notification to the app? or D- pin rising edge?

Comment: @Hanan can you answer my questions?

Comment: I ask to close this question because it is not related to programming
You can follow links and so on by accessing topics on pages related to Arduino or Rasperi
You can program Arduino to get comprehensive information about the phone connected to it and either the Android phones can not switch information between them via USB

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest file register a broadcast receiver for action

```
android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED
```